# Branch Custom Domain SSL

Tags: branch.io

io for universal links and using custom domain for the same however after pointing the ns records to the hostnames mentioned in the page Im getting a untrusted certificate error. In branch dashboard Im getting we could not authenticate the validity error.

Answer (score 0):

Branch will push an SSL certificate to the domain, however this can take a couple of hours to get updated. You can reach out to Branch support if an SSL certificate is not assigned to this domain after a few hours.